# Расположение WebSocketCLient-а в архитектуре MVVM (Android)

Tags: android, mvvm, websocket, webrtc

подскажите плиз, в какой слой в MVVM стоит совать класс WebSocketClient?

(Спрашиваю потому что в нем есть метод onMessage, который должен проактивно дергать некие методы в UI; а мы знаем, что дата- и домен-слои про UI ничего знать не должны; получается что в дата слой класть его некорректно.)

(Как бонус, тот же вопрос интересует про расположение класса Android-RTC-клиента.)

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: а как вы дергаете обычный сетевой запрос, по нажатию на кнопку, по такой логике?

Comment: дергаю suspend fun, которая возвращает (или не возвращает) нечто, собственно нажатием на кнопку ‍♂️. А когда дергается onMessage в сокете, это должно вызвать какоето действие на UI без моего действия.

Comment: когда дергается onMessage в сокете, данные должны сохраняться куда-то в дата-слой, а UI обновляться по подписке на эти данные.

Comment: +1 к товарищу выше. а раз вы используете корутины - то отлично подойдет тут сохранять их в горячий flow (State/Shared Flow)

Comment: Спасибо, теперь яснее